# Apply DateObject to a whole list

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time

I'm trying to apply DataObject to a whole list.
It looks something like this.

`{"6/03/2020", "10/03/2020", "10/03/2020", "12/03/2020", "12/03/2020", \ "13/03/2020",...}` This list is called dF.

I tried to use Map

```
data3 = Map[DateObject[{"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}], dF]
```

But gives out something like this:

```
{DateObject[{"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}]["6/03/2020"], 
DateObject[{"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}]["10/03/2020"],..}
```

Doing it individualy works just fine using part.

```
df1 = DateObject[{Part[dF, 1], {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}]
```

So i resorted to using For and adding each of the elemts to an empty list.
It worked but was way to slow (about 20 min of computing). The list has about 100k elements.

Is there a faster way to do this? I´m new to mathematica so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `DateObject[{#, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}] & /@ dF`  -- there's an extra set of braces that are hard to see.